# undefined method `normalize' in service object MetaInspector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use the url entered by a user to gather the title, description, root_url, scheme and host for that URL.

Right now, I am getting this error as soon as I call MetaInspector:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `normalize' for nil:NilClass:
```

Help will be extremely appreciated here. I have tried many things without any conclusive results. What am I missing?

Here's my code:

I hit the links#new view..

**Logs**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `normalize' for nil:NilClass:



metainspector (5.2.1) lib/meta_inspector/url.rb:83:in `normalized'
  metainspector (5.2.1) lib/meta_inspector/url.rb:50:in `url='
  metainspector (5.2.1) lib/meta_inspector/url.rb:12:in `initialize'
  metainspector (5.2.1) lib/meta_inspector/document.rb:31:in `initialize'
  metainspector (5.2.1) lib/meta_inspector.rb:20:in `new'
  app/services/get_meta.rb:11:in `new_record'
  app/controllers/links_controller.rb:8:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I have two models: `Link` and `Domain`

Models:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :links

end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :domain

end
```

**Tables**

```
# Table name: links
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  url        :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

# Table name: domains
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  root_url   :string
#  scheme     :string
#  host       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
```

**Links Controller**

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def create
    @link = GetMeta.new(params[:url]).new_record

    redirect_to root_url

  end

  private

  def link_params
    params.require(:link).permit(:url, :created_at, :updated_at)
  end
end
```

**Service Object: Get_Meta.rb**

```
class GetMeta
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def new_record

    #https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector
    page = MetaInspector.new(@url)

    Link.create! do |link|
      link.url = page.url
      link.title = page.title
      link.description = page.description

      link.domain.build(root_url: page.root, scheme: page.scheme, host: page.host)

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the relevant lines from the stacktrace are these two:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `normalize' for nil:NilClass:
metainspector (5.2.1) lib/meta_inspector/url.rb:83:in `normalized'
```

From the message, you can already guess that something is nil that metainspector was assuming wouldn't be. But lets follow the stacktrace just to be sure.

A you list in your comment (thanks for that BTW it's really a good idea!) the project is here: https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector

If you click that then look for the file listed: `lib/meta_inspector/url.rb:83`
and look at line 83 as specified above, you get this:

```
# Normalize url to deal with characters that should be encoded,
# add trailing slash, convert to downcase...
def normalized(url)
  Addressable::URI.parse(url).normalize.to_s
```

so... normalized in metainspector is expecting there to actually be a url... and is freaking out when it's nil. So that confirms that the problem is that there is no url being passed into metainspector.

This means you need to check for that before passing in the url... or at least figure out why you're not passing throught he url... whic I think I can see why here:

This line indicated that the params are likely to come through as: `{:link => {:url => 'some_url'}}`

```
  params.require(:link).permit(:url, :created_at, :updated_at)
```

which you'd access with `params[:link][:url]`

but your code that uses the url is:

```
 @link = GetMeta.new(params[:url]).new_record
```

so I'd change the usage above to the below and you should be good to go

```
 @link = GetMeta.new(params[:link][:url]).new_record
```

Comment: I have made the requested changed but the params[:url] still doesn't pass.

Here's what my binding.pry looks like:

     8: def new_record
     9:   binding.pry
    10:   #https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector
 => 11:   page = MetaInspector.new(@url)

@url                     nil
page                     nil

Comment: Please don't post a  link... links go stale and we want the question to be forever. update your question and add the new code :) Also: `params[:url]` will never work - it should be `params[:link][:url]`